# How to teach Zabbix to be smart about short spikes in events?

Tags: zabbix

Recently I've started to receive alerts from Zabbix about high iowait at one of our servers. This event is caused by pg_dump backing up our database and it's perfectly ok because the spike is short and... well, because backing up is a legitimate activity at the server.

Is there a way to teach Zabbix to be smart about such things? I think there is no need to send email alerts about one short (<30secs) spike of iowait per day. On the other hand, if server day is full of 5-secs spikes, this should be investigated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most popular and easiest way is to use proper trigger functions. For example, instead of what you most likely use, `last()`, go for `min(60)` or `avg(60)`. Minimum would not detect repeated spiking, average might.

Other potentially useful [trigger functions](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/appendix/triggers/functions) for this purpose:

- `regexp()` (mostly for text items)
- `str()` (mostly for text items)
- `count()`

Note that `last()` cannot return or evaluate multiple values, thus `last()` = `last(0)` = `last(300)`.